# Unknown props warnings when rendering PieChart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

When I tried to render Legend component with content, I got this error.

*warning.js:36 Warning: Unknown props `verticalAlign`, `layout`, `align`, `iconType`, `iconSize`, `payload`, `chartWidth`, `chartHeight`, `margin`, `onBBoxUpdate` on  tag.*

This is the Legend code for get multiple content,

```
const renderContent = (content, props) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(content)) {
    return React.cloneElement(content, props);
  } else if (_.isFunction(content)) {
    return content(props);
  }

  return React.createElement(DefaultLegendContent, props);
};
```

That's why, it gets unknown props warning.Therefore how can I remove these parents props in child component.

```
 //Legend tag
    <Legend verticalAlign="middle" layout="vertical" align="right" iconType="circle" content={this._LegendWithValues()}

//Custom legend content
 _LegendWithValues = () => {
        return (
            <ul className="cui-legend-content">
                {
                    this.props.data.map((entry, index) => (
                        <li key={`item-${index}` }>
                            <svg height="20" width="20">
                                <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" strokeWidth="3" fill={this._getColorScheme()[index]}/>
                            </svg>
                            <text style={ul_style} >{entry.name}:{entry.unit} {entry.value}</text>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe related to how `cloneElement` clones props? 
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7692

You can extract the undesired props as in the example above.